# Why some files aren't watched with a File Watcher [PhpStorm 2016.1]

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, filesystemwatcher, jetbrains-ide, file-watcher

I setup a File Watcher on my PhpStorm 2016.1 and I have a strange issue.

[image]

Some files are watched, and some aren't. Sometime it depends on their locations, sometime on their types. I just can't put a finger on which pattern some files aren't watched.

I only want to execute a shell script every time a file is modified.

Did you ever experienced this kind of issue on PhpStorm or do you have any idea where I should dig a little more?

Comment: According to the screenshot, the scope is set to "Project Files". In this case File Watcher won't trigger on excluded files (i.e. ones under excluded folders in "Settings | Directories",  with red background in Project View).
Please make sure you don't edit excluded files.

Comment: @Sergey.Simonchik The files that aren't watched are included in the project. I already checked that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, then it's a bug. Unfortunately, not reproduced for me.
Could you please enable debug logging for `#com.intellij.plugins.watcher` category (on the main menu "Help | Debug Log Settings..."), restart WebStorm, recreate the issue and attach your idea.log ("Help | Show Log in Finder") to a newly created issue in the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues. Thanks.